# Some plain text mails have a different font

Tags: fonts, thunderbird, encoding

(Ubuntu 10.04 · Thunderbird 17.0.5)

I read all my mails as plain text (<kbd>View → Message Body As → Plain text</kbd>). Usually they all are in the same font with the same font size:

[image: Thunderbird: mail: screenshot: same/default font]

But once in a while I get a mail which is displayed in a different font/font size:

[image: Thunderbird: mail: screenshot: different font]

At <kbd>Edit → Preferences → Display → Formatting → Advanced…</kbd> I have the [same settings for all](https://askubuntu.com/a/156655/82665) languages/charsets. I also deactivated "Allow messages to use other fonts".

What is the reason for the font difference?

The encoding of this particular mail seems to be *Chinese Simplified (GB2312)*, at least according to <kbd>View → Character Encoding</kbd>. So I changed every font setting for *Simplified Chinese* (to test it), but nothing changed in the mail.

At [this thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2490167) the solution (for TB 13) was to change the font settings for *Other Languages*. But I don't have this option in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the "Other Languages" hint. That fixed my problem with font sizes!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you're seeing spam that tries to evade detection with similar-looking letters in faraway Unicode planes, similar to how [upside-down](http://upsidedown.info/) [text](http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/upside-down.htm) is achieved. Try copy-pasting it inside gedit, which will probably have the same behaviour as Thunderbird (requests a single font but gets a fallback font for rendering unusual characters).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. In fact this unusual mail is spam. I analyzed some letters with [`unicode`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/lucid/unicode). It tells me that e.g. the "D" in "Dear" is "U+0044 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D", so nothing unusual, right? FWIW, here is the first line: `Dear Purchasing Manager`. So looks like the usual chars to me.

Comment: Here is the char analysis (at *rishida.net*) for the first paragraph: http://tinyurl.com/thunderbirdfontissue

Comment: Nothing unusual, you're right. It must be Thunderbird-specific.